# Listbox not updating when field inside observablecollection is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I currently have an issue with my ObservableCollection that is databound to a listbox. Whenever I update a field inside of my ObservableCollection in the backend, the UI never refreshes, i have to null the list and reassign it to the binding for the UI to update. Any idea as to why this is happening? I've tried a lot of things but nothing changes. I'd rather not have to force the UI to update everytime I change a textfield inside of my collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on the items of the collection, i.e. raise the `PropertyChanged` event when one of their properties changes.

`ObservableCollection` only notifies if an element is added or removed.